# Fill in info with most recent value, or with first available value if no recent info

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| category | user_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.01 |
| A | 2 | 0.05 |
| A | 5 | 0.09 |
| A | 7 | 0.12 |
| B | 2 | 0.34 |
| B | 3 | 0.27 |
| B | 6 | 0.08 |
| B | 7 | 0.12 |

**The data needs to be filled up to the max value of user_id for both categories (A and B). So 1-7 for A and for B. The data must use the value for the previous/most recent user_id for its category. If there isn't one, then it must use the first available value for its category.**

**Here's what I'm trying to get it to look like:**

| category | user_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.01 |
| A | 2 | 0.05 |
| A | 3 | 0.05 |
| A | 4 | 0.05 |
| A | 5 | 0.09 |
| A | 6 | 0.09 |
| A | 7 | 0.12 |
| B | 1 | 0.34 |
| B | 2 | 0.34 |
| B | 3 | 0.27 |
| B | 4 | 0.27 |
| B | 5 | 0.27 |
| B | 6 | 0.08 |
| B | 7 | 0.12 |

So for 'category' B 'user_id' 1, since it was the most recent/lowest value, it used the next available from B2.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `category` VARCHAR(2),
  `user_id` INT(2), 
  `value` DECIMAL(3,2)
 );
INSERT INTO table_1
(`category`, `user_id`, `value`)
VALUES
('A', 1, 0.01),
('A', 2, 0.05),
('A', 5, 0.09),
('A', 7, 0.12),
('B', 2, 0.34),
('B', 3, 0.27),
('B', 6, 0.08),
('B', 7, 0.12)
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use a query like below.

Also here's a [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5580dcf5ab6bda918d4deecf578be141)

**Explanation:**

1. first we need a numbers table to get all numbers to a sufficient range here 5000
2. then we get max values of table_1 per category
3. then we cross above two get all numbers per category to the max value
4. next we get reference user_id index of values to be pushed in for all missing user_id
5. finally we join to get actual values for all user_ids. Special case of B-1 which does not exists is handled via window function

**Query:**

```
SET @@cte_max_recursion_depth  = 5000;
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS i
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i+1
   FROM cte
   WHERE i < 3000
), maxuserids as 
(
select category, max(user_id) as m from table_1 group by category
), leftsidetable as (
SELECT *
FROM cte cross join maxuserids
where m>=i
), refvalues as (
select 
l.category, l.i, max(user_id) m 
from leftsidetable l left join table_1 t1
on l.category=t1.category and l.i>=t1.user_id 
group by l.category, l.i
)
select r.category, r.i as user_id, 
ifnull(value, 
lead(value) over (partition by r.category order by r.i)) value  from refvalues r 
left join table_1 t 
on t.category=r.category and t.user_id=r.m
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Where do you learn this level of SQL? The problem was so specific that I didn't even know where to begin and searched for a while through different potential options before I just gave up and asked.